# NuGet package - readme.txt being added to target project, instead of just being displayed

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, readme

I'm responsible for a library published in our company as a NuGet package, and I followed the "[Adding a readme and other files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#adding-a-readme-and-other-files)" guide to show a readme.txt containing important changes when users install or update the package when using Visual Studio. This works - i.e. when you install the package the readme.txt is displayed. However when you install the package this readme.txt files is also being copied into the root directory of the target project.

Does anyone know how I can stop this (i.e. show the readme.txt when install, but *don't* add it to the target project)? It's quite useful for users to see this file, but confusing if it gets added to the project.

The .nuspec for the library like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <projectUrl>http://example.com/blah/blah</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="README.txt" target="" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The packing + pushing is normally performed by a TeamCity build step, but if I build the pkg using the following command line then the same behaviour is present:

```
$ nuget pack MyLibrary.csproj
$ nuget push MyLibrary-{version}.nupkg -source {internal-nuget-server}
```

Comment: How about this issue now? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hey Leo - I'll just add a new Answer describing my solution. The problem lay in the .csproj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here was that I had the `README.txt` included in the `.csproj` file using `<Content include...>` when really it should have been `<None include...>` - sorry this was somewhat of a Red Herring since I didn't include this information in my question!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how I can stop this

To reolve this issue, make sure you are pack the `.nuspec` file and the `README.txt` file in the `<files>` section **not target to** `content`. Following is my test steps:

1. Create a test sample project "`TestReadmeFile`"
2. Create `.nupsec` file in the same folder as `TestReadmeFile.csproj` by the command `nuget.exe spec "TestReadmeFile.csproj"`, then replacement tokens defined($id$, $version$, etc.)
3. Add a  section in the nuspec file, containing only readme.txt, like this: `<file src="readme.txt" target="" />`

Following is my .nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>TestReadmeFile</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\TestReadmeFile.dll" target="lib\net462" />
    <file src="README.txt" target="" />
  </files>
</package>
```

4. Pack the .nuspec by the command line: `nuget.exe pack "TestReadmeFile.csproj.nuspec"`

After create that package, the package will open the readme.txt automatically **without** adding it to the target project.

Comment: Hi Liu, I had same problem and the reason I came to this point is that VS 2017 integrates Nuget specs into csproj file so I removed nuspec file. So I do not see point in going back to nuspec again in order to display readme file.